# Cannot bind to the property or column States on the DataSource

Tags: winforms, binding

Why this work :

```
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        exCheckedListBox1.DataSource = Profiles;
        this.exCheckedListBox1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Tag", this, "States", true));

    }

    CheckedBindingList Profiles = new CheckedBindingList();

    public int States
    {
        get
        {
            return Profiles.States;
        }
        set
        {
            Profiles.States = value;
        }
    }

}

public class CheckedBindingList : List<string>
{
    public int States { get; set; }
}
```

but when change binding to

```
this.exCheckedListBox1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Tag", this.Profiles, "States", true));
```

throw the Exception ?
Thanks all very very very. I try to bind filed from my custom list class that inherit form List.

Exception - Cannot bind to the property or column States on the DataSource.
Parameter name: dataMember

Comment: It would help us if you showed us the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Seems System.Windows.Forms.Binding parameter dataSource cannot be a class that inherits from List< T >

This solves the problem:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
    }

    CheckedBindingList Profiles = new CheckedBindingList();
    SomeClass some_class = new SomeClass();

    public int States
    {
        get
        {
            return Profiles.States;
        }
        set
        {
            Profiles.States = value;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        exCheckedListBox1.DataSource = Profiles;
        exCheckedListBox1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Tag", some_class, "States", true));
    }
}
public class CheckedBindingList : List<string>
{
    public int States { get; set; }
}
public class SomeClass
{
    public int States { get; set; }
}
```